# Training a machine learning model to recognize sentiment in text

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am just getting started with TensorFlow and machine learning. I have watched the following demo video showing how TensorFlow can be used to train a model to [recognize sentiment in the text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_hzMnRXjhI).

In the demo, a dataset containing news headlines, classified as sarcastic or not, is used to train a model. The model is built with a `binary_crossentropy` loss, with the test data is_sarcastic value set to 1 if the headline is sarcastic and 0 if it is not.

Assuming I want to build a model to detect the "happiness" sentiment in a sentence and have tens of thousands of sentences to build my model with, including:

1. Today is the best day of my life.
2. I am feeling good.
3. I hate my life and want to disappear.
4. I am doing okay.
5. I am a little sad.
6. My dog is 7 years old.

If I am interested in determining the degree of happiness associated with a given sentence, should I classify each of the sentences with a binary value (ex: 1 and 0 - Happy / Not Happy) like in the TensorFlow example, or should I use a more "precise" way to categorize each of the demo sentences, with a "degree" of happiness? For example, 2 is very happy, 1 is happy, 0 is neutral or N/A, -1 is sad, -2 is very sad. For the given sentences, the degree of happiness would be:

1. Today is the best day of my life (2)
2. I am feeling good (1)
3. I hate my life and want to disappear (-2)
4. I am doing okay (0)
5. I am a little sad (-1)
6. My dog is 7 years old (0)

If the first option is used, how should I categorize neutral or N/A sentences (4 and 6) to build my model with?

If the second option is used, would it make sense to have a `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss and multiply the weight of each of the predicted "happiness degree" for a test sentence. For example, the predicted happiness level for the sentence "I am doing great" would be something like: $(0.68 * +2) + (0.24 * +1) + (0.04 * 0) + (0.04 * - 1) + (0.02 * -2) = 1.52,$ which would indicate a very happy feeling.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This looks more like an ordinal regression problem as it has only a few categories with a numeric relationship between them.

There has been a lot of research in the steam, and one of the implementations is spacecutter ordinal regression.

https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2018/12/06/spacecutter-ordinal-regression/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/265430)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback mdewey. I will consider this approach in the future.